# Apply condition to multiple elements of a vector? Warning message: the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Tags: r, function, conditional-statements

I'm running a bunch of regression models, screening covariates for confounding, and wrote a function to make the process easier by only displaying regression results on the console if the covariate is a confounder. Below is some random, sample data to illustrate the idea:

```
Var1 <- c(2.3940, 4.3848, 4.2840, 5.37393, 19.383948)
Var2 <- c(383, 4840, 38404, 48403, 8302)
data <- data.frame(Var1, Var2)
attach(data)
```

One of my covariates is a factor variable with three levels:

```
Var3 <- c(3938, 48403, 585038, 383028, 474937)
Var4 <- c(.373938, .473038, .830937, .3830938, 1.203)
Var5 <- as.factor(c("Ever", "Sometimes", "Never", "Sometimes", "Ever"))
Covariates <- data.frame(Var3, Var4, Var5)
```

And the function:

```
confounder <- function(model) {
  model.sum <- summary(model)
  model.b <- model.sum$coefficients[2, 1]
  oldmodel <- update(model, . ~ . - x)
  oldmodel.sum <- summary(oldmodel)
  oldmodel.b <- oldmodel.sum$coefficients[2, 1]
  model.frame <- tidy(model)
  newvar.b <- model.frame[grep("x", model.frame$term), 5]
  if (abs(model.b - oldmodel.b)/abs(model.b) >= .1 | newvar.b < .05) {
    return(model.sum)
  }
}
```

Then I run it using lapply:

```
lapply(Covariates, function(x) {
  confounder(lm(Var1 ~ Var2 + x))
})
```

And I get this error message:

```
Warning messages:
1: In if (abs(model.b - oldmodel.b)/abs(model.b) >= 0.1 | newvar.b <  :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (abs(model.b - oldmodel.b)/abs(model.b) >= 0.1 | newvar.b <  :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

How do I change this function to apply the condition when I get to a factor variable with multiple levels?  Essentially, if any of the levels of the factor variable fit the condition, not just the first one, I want the console to display the regression output. Hope this makes sense.

Thanks!

Comment: Good question ... please include all `library` lines as `tidy()` is not base R.

Comment: Also, it is highly inadvisable to use `attach`.  You can typically substitute it using `with`. Many functions (like `lm`, `glm`, and `plot`) have a data argument, which will also negate the need for `attach`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `any()` function in your if statement:

```
confounder <- function(model) {
  model.sum <- summary(model)
  model.b <- model.sum$coefficients[2, 1]
  oldmodel <- update(model, . ~ . - x)
  oldmodel.sum <- summary(oldmodel)
  oldmodel.b <- oldmodel.sum$coefficients[2, 1]
  model.frame <- tidy(model)
  newvar.b <- model.frame[grep("x", model.frame$term), 5]
  if (any(abs(model.b - oldmodel.b)/abs(model.b) >= .1 | newvar.b < .05)) {
    return(model.sum)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I did not know about the any function, but seems like it will be a very useful one to add to the toolkit.